# change the iframe url from the same iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I need to change the iframe url from the same iframe.
For example: "**http://parent.com**" is the Parent Domain URL of my website with an http
and: "**https://iframe.com**"  is the iframe Domain URL with an https. The two domains are different.

Here's the code of the parent window:

```
  <html>
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <script>
        function sheck19()
        {
          document.getElementById("myFrame19").height="700";
          document.getElementById('myFrame19').src="https://iframe.com/home.php";
        }
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe id="myFrame19" src="https://iframe.com/index.php" width="620" height="410" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </body>
  </html>
```

and here's the code of the iframe document:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function uuui() {
        window.parent.sheck19();
      };
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <input  name="Continuer" type="submit" value="Continuer" onclick="uuui();">
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: And the question is? Does it work or not, and if not, what errors are you getting?

Comment: Of course it did not work and when I open the cmd of my browser appear to me this message:
Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin https: // iframe.com from accessing a frame with origin http: // parent.com. Protocols, domains, and ports must match.

Comment: So why not specifically ask for that, and add the error message, right now you're not really asking a question. On the other hand, had you searched for "cross domain iframe access" you would have found hundreds of answers telling you that you can't do this, and maybe even an [article on javascripts same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).

Comment: A parent website cannot communicate with an iframe or vice-versa for security reasons: a parent website then gets the opportunity to hijack an iframe by commanding it to do something bad.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is not possible. If the two domain are different you cannot communicate in the way you're trying. The Browsers Same-origin policy will prevent it.

What you can do is use the window.postMessage API. Read more about that here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage. It's pretty widely supported: IE8+, FF6+Safari 4+, Chrome 1+, Opera 9.5+

```
 otherWindow.postMessage(message, targetOrigin, [transfer]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest, but i did not understand what you mean ,do I need to radically change the code?

Comment: please can you assist me, because I am beginner in this area :/

Comment: Yes, your code will not work. You have to radically change it. Read the link I posted and if you still have questions after that let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing a parent page's URL is not allowed if the iframe and the main page are not in the same (sub)domain. However, if you just need URL of the main page (i.e. the browser URL), you can try this

```
var url = (window.location != window.parent.location) ? document.referrer: document.location;
```

This has worked for me in the past.